# Unable to link the bot built from bot composer with twilio

Tags: twilio, botframework, chatbot, twilio-programmable-chat

We have built a bot using bot composer, and deployed it as azure function and the web app, the URL looks like https://xyzbot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
We tested it using bot emulator and the web chat, worked fine.
Facing some challenges while registering the bot with twilio channel.
When we used the same link in twilio webhook, it is giving following bad request error.

[image: error from Twilio]

Comment: I can find nothing in the [Bot Framework Composer docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/) about hooking a Composer created bot up to Twilio. Can you point me in the direction of that documentation, or any docs on how `/api/messages` should respond for your bot?

Comment: Here is the link how we can [link][1] the bot with twilio


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-twilio?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: Did you follow the process for [wiring up the Twilio adapter in your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-twilio?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#wiring-up-the-twilio-adapter-in-your-bot)?

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5094

Comment: @AkshayH - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney Thanks for jumping in here. I can help from the Twilio side of things, but I'm less sure of the Bot Composer side. Hope we can meet in the middle to solve this!